# Visual Studio 2010 VSTO Excel 2007 multilanguage?

Tags: excel, vsto, multilingual

I have to add multilanguage support to several existing VSTO Excel AddIns. Adding this to the user controls etc. was relatively easy, but now I have to add multilanguage support for existing entries in Excel Files. These files are used as templates. 
Does anybody know how to do this, without replacing the cell-entries by code but with resources files or anything like that?